# Vue 3 composition API - creating custom plugin with Typescript type augmenting

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have some issue with proper display plugin in `<script>` and `<template>` tags on webstorm.

First of all my files and configuration

**tsconfig.config.json**

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "vitest.config.*", "cypress.config.*", "playwright.config.*", "src/i18n.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.0.28",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.12",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-checker": "^0.5.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.12"
  }
}
```

**Project structure**
[image]

I have created custom i18n plugin (i have clear vue project) for testing pupropse.

File structure is base on vue 3 documentation:

https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#augmenting-global-properties

Just like above file structure i create **i18n.ts** file

```
import type {App} from "vue";

export default {
    install(app: App, options: any) {
        app.config.globalProperties.$translation = (key: string) =>  {
                const keys = key.split('.');
                return keys.reduce((o: any, i) => {
                    if (o) return o[i]
                }, options);
            }
        }
    }
```

And also for type augmenting **i18n.d.ts** that is also included in tsconfig file

```
export{}

declare module 'vue' {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $translation: (key: string) => string;
    }
}
```

**main.ts** looks like belov

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

import 'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css'      //theme
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css'                 //core css
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css'                           //icons

import './assets/main.css'
import i18n from "@/plugins/i18n"
import pl from "@/plugins/pl.json"

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(PrimeVue)
app.use(i18n, pl)
app.mount('#app')
```

**pl.json** is simple json file

```
{
  "some": {
    "key": "test"
  }
}
```

And im trying to use this plugin in **Home.vue** (this is the main page that is routed in App.vue)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-color="'red'" />
    {{$translation('some.key')}}
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

import {onMounted} from "vue";

const vColor = {
  mounted: (el: HTMLElement, bind: { value: string}) => {
    el.style.color = bind.value;
  }
}

const test = $translation('some.key');

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(test)
})

</script>
```

In template a have the following warning, but on runtime it works

[image]

In script section when i add this plugin i causes error

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: You need to import $translation in script section any way. Global variables (not properties) can't appear out of nowhere.  The problem in the template is specific to IDE. If the error doesn't appear on build, it shouldn't be addressed in general. Possibly means that the type wasn't hooked up properly. Try `declare module '@vue/runtime-core'` instead of `declare module 'vue'`

Comment: Yes, thanks template problem was solved when declare module as @vue/runtime-core but since $translate IDE does not help from which dir should i import my plugin. The same directory as @vue/runtime-core does not work.
When i tried import it form i18n.d.ts it shows below eror:
`TS2305: Module '"@/i18n"' has no exported member '$translation'`

Comment: You aren't supposed to import d.ts directly, they are picked up by either tsconfig `types` section, or `<reference>`. If you need to import $translate from somewhere, you need to explicitly define an export in your plugin

Comment: I have searched from other topics but only what i found is to export some interface with similar signature like `export interface I18n { $translation: (key: string) => string }`.
I do something in i18n.ts in plugin folder but i couldnt realize how to export this part and use it in script component. Could you tell me more how to achive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to import `$translation` in script section any way, global variables (not properties) can't appear out of nowhere, unless some kind of magic transforms like Unplugin are used. In order to do that, it should be exported:

```
export let $translation: (key: string) => string;

export const plugin = {
    install(app: App, options: any) {
        $translation = (key: string) =>  {...};
        app.config.globalProperties.$translation = $translation
    }
}
```

For Vue 3, `@vue/runtime-core` type augmentation can be tried instead of `vue`:

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $translation: (key: string) => string;
    }
}
```